# Cannot get Xalan to run any example

Tags: xslt, xalan

I downloaded `Xalan-Java Version 2.7.1`, unpack it, and then set the `PATH` for java and `CLASSPATH` for xalan:

```
set path=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;c:\Xalan\
```

(I also tried setting the classpath only for xalan.jar, xercesImpl.jar, xml-apis.jar)

When testing a simple Hello World example (or any other example):

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in hello.xml -xsl hello.xsl -out hello.html
```

I always get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/xslt
/Process
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.  Program will exit
```

What is the problem ? Someone has an idee ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried following [instruction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-xalanj/x-xalanj-pdf.pdf)?

Comment: yes, that too, and many others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did to make it work, finally:

Copy the `xalan.jar` to the `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\`
Running the file like this from command line:

```
java -classpath "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\
lib\xalan.jar";"c:\xalan-j_2_7_1\serializer.jar" org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -
in hello.xml -xsl hello.xsl
```

Without `serializer.jar` it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

Serializer should not be needed in all cases.  For example, if you XSLT was making use of  pipeDocument then it would be needed.

This error points to not finding "org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process" of xalan.jar.  Recheck your classpath.  Exclude hello.xml and hello.xsl to avoid them muddying the water.   If your classpath is correct, this alone

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process
```

will provide output (Xalan-J command line options).