# Could not find the main class: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process

Tags: xslt, xalan

As part of a project, I have been asked to carry out an XML to HTML transformation. I have to use Xalan Version 2.7.0.

However when I set the  CLASSPATH for xalan in command prompt:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;I:\Xalan\xalan-j_2_7_0\xalan.jar
```

and try to carry out the transformation as follows:

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in Multimedia\StudentDeals.xml -xsl Multimedia\StudentDeals.xsl -out Multimedia\Deals.html
```

I always get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/xslt
/Process
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process.  Program will exit
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8200380/14419

Answer (score 5):

Following the link that Mads Hansen provided above, I tried things out. I got it working all right, without having to specify serializer.jar in the classpath, but I did include the classpath option in the call itself:

```
java -classpath D:\XSLT_engines\xalan-j_2_7_1\xalan.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in input.xml -xsl transformation.xsl -out output.xml
```